# mouseenter rollover effect only works after second entry

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

*I've tried to find similar posts on this specific matter with little success so hopefully someone a little more experienced with JQuery could shed light on my problem.
I'm currently working on a portfolio site, i.e. alot of images. I wanted to make a Jquery rollover effect when you hover above one of the thumbnail images presented on the site.*

The effect itself has been achieve but it comes with a sort of bug. **Whenever I refresh the page or view the page anew, whenever I my mouse enters the image container element which should trigger the Jquery effect, it doesn't do so the first time, but when I try it a second time without refreshing the page, the effect is there.**

Here is the basic html markup:

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <article class="ImageContainer">
             <a href="#">
                 <img class="back" src="Images/Image1.jpg" alt="Image1"/>
                 <span class="over" style="display: none;">
                     <h2>Title</h2>
                     <p>Watch Project</p>
                 </span>
            </a>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

So as you can see I've solved my "rollover effect" with a "display: none" solution which I later let my Jquery code "fadeIn" to make it visible on the mouseenter effect.

Below is the CSS for span class="over", probably not necessary to show but just incase.

```
.over {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image:url(Images/over.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left 0px;
}
```

And now for my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $(".ImageContainer").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(".ImageContainer").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

It seems the problem only arise when viewing it in a browser, this jsfiddle seems to work without issue. I am at loss as to why. All my links to my other documents also work and I have jquery and jquery UI linked.

http://jsfiddle.net/LRdR9/

**SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM:
my .over class didn't have "display: block;" which caused the browser to not see it. Upon second mouseenter it automatically put it there itself. It tricked me thinking I had another issue.**

Comment: If you have to "recap", your question is too long. Remove the chatter and state the question!

Comment: Really? Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/LRdR9/

Comment: if I'm not mistaking, `$('a > span', this).fadeIn(200);` should also work.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you can simplify the selector in your functions by changing $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(200); to  $(".over").fadeIn(200);

Comment: @EmmyS That will fade in all elements with a class of over, not the child of the currently hovered element.

Comment: That is weird. It does seem to work fine in the jsfiddle however the issue persists. Working in dreamweaver currently. Could there be something stopping the Jquery action for from executing the first time but not for the rest? I'm so confused. Can't begin to think what that could be even.

Comment: @RichardDalton - yes, you're right. I was assuming it was only the one instance, in which case it does work.

Comment: @user125697 What could cause something to work in a jsfiddle but not in a browser? I'm at loss as to why.

Comment: @EmmyS - I tried entering what you wrote into my js script file in dreamweaver, upon refresh and viewing it in chrome the whole effect was gone. Am I missing a plug-in? I have the latest Jquery and Jquery UI linked.

Comment: @JohanEspling - as RichardDalton pointed out, my code is incorrect if you have more than one element with the "over" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to work in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRdR9/).

Note that in your jsFiddle you are running your code `onload` - make sure you're doing that in your file itself (be sure to place your jQuery inside the body, not the head). Also, make sure you're testing it in multiple browsers.

P.s. You could shorten your code to the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.ImageContainer', function () {
        $('a > span', this).fadeToggle(200);
   });
}):
```

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRdR9/1/).

Comment: This helped me to better structure my code! What I just found solved my issue which was by coincidence. I didn't have a display: block; for my class="over", which caused the style to be "none" and then the browser automatically inserted the display: block;. I was tricked into thinking it was another sort of issue.